# What causes "com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream"?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, scala

I'm getting this on an AWS ECS container, and using MongoDB Atlas. I've looked at other SO questions, and they don't seem to help.

I'd expect to receive a "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused" exception if it were a connectivity issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was a connectivity issue. To troubleshoot, I briefly enabled connectivity from anywhere in the MongoDB Atlas console.

The problem was that I was using the "Standard Connection" URI rather than the "Private Endpoint" URI.